# How can I edit all columns of my Google Drive spreadsheets?

Tags: nexus-7, google-drive

When I open Google Drive on my web browser (Firefox) I can edit every column in every row of all my gDrive spreadsheets. When I try to edit one of the spreadsheets on my Nexus 7, I can only edit the first two columns. It's a large spreadsheet because it's something like a scientific laboratory book. Another spreadsheet can be edited without limits. So what is wrong with the spreadsheet I cannot edit? Is there any setting I have to change? How can I edit the rest of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Seems like i am not the only one with this problem. I don't know, maybe it's not a setting but a bug?

Comment: Have you tried the Google Docs app? It was updated recently and actually has a real editor for spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of gDrive fixes this problem, however the offline-compatibility is worse.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Drive app by default opens spreadsheets in List view - a sort of data-entry only mode in which you can edit data but not equations.

You can select spreadsheet view - this used to be in a link at the bottom of the spreadsheet which involved zooming right out, now it seems to be at the top toward the left (this may vary by app/android version). You may need to force it to continue to the desktop view - it will warn you that you may not have access to all features.

Once in spreadsheet mode (which is a little ropey) you should be able to edit any columns.

Comment: The new version of gDrive fixes this problem, however the offline-compatibility is worse.